# Websphere application modify web.xml doesn't work

Tags: websphere, web.xml

I have deployed applications in `Websphere 8.5`, and I want to modify `web.xml`, but it seems not working. What I am supposed to do?

Comment: What are you trying to modify, how, and what is not working?

Comment: modify filter in web.xml. But in Websphere, only modifywb.xml is not working.

Answer (score 3):

While there are documented [ways of updating enterprise application files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/crun_app_upgrade.html), those were conceived for multi-server deployments and partly are legacy of the previous decade of monster application servers. They are inconvenient for making changes to local development server and it wastes a lot of time.

Upon application deployment, WAS creates (copies/updates) deployment descriptors in the `config` directory. Then `web.xml` is used from that location.

You are probably changing `web.xml` in the location where original application files are kept, thus no effect. You should change the one in `config\cells\<cell_name>\applications\<ear_name>\deployments\<app_name>\<war_name>\WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere writes a second file named web_merged.xml. If you only update the web.xml and replace it you will not update the runtime file used by the container.

Best result I had was using the single file upload function provided within the Admin console or to use the wsadmin or jacl cmd.

Comment: where is the web_merged.xml file usually?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to update application via console/script.
But I'm assuming you are editing file directly (very hard to guess from your description, I've asked you to describe your procedure).

You need to restart the application to pick up changes in `web.xml`. See the [Hot deploy in WAR files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade_war.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Update web.xml with WebSphere Web Console
- Update web_merged.xml at the same time, and also update the two files in `config\cells\<cell_name>\applications\<ear_name>\deployments\<app_name>\<war_name>\WEB-INF`